# Download Excel file from web url using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, amazon-s3

I am trying to create an application that crawls a website providing free financial data in .xlsx format. They upload files once a month and not always on the same day.

Is it possible to download any new files from a specific URL and dump it into my S3 bucket, before reading it into a database? I have read up about creating a worker using Sidekiq. I expect that this will play a crucial part in the process.

Can anybody perhaps give some advice or point me to a tutorial that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and you don't even need `Sidekiq`.
Take a look at [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html), and do the following things:

1. Just write a ruby script that downloads the xlsx files then upload to S3. Be sure the script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, and give it execute permission.
2. Add this script to your crontab jobs, and make it run everyday.